# multiple UIButtons for one action, read the current button and store it as a temp value

Tags: ios, uibutton, uislider

I'm a beginner working on an emotion annotation application. There are several buttons like "happy","angry" and etc... All the buttons will call a same action. And there is an UISlider. If you click on "happy" , then you adjust the slider to annotate how happy you are now. After that you click on button "angry", the current value of slider will be stored in an float variable relatived to the last button, like "happy". Then you adjust the same slider to annotate  how "angry" you are. And the next button....
I don't have idea about how to store the slider value for the last button...
Are there any ideas?
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this. One of the most simple solutions is to tag your buttons, and then use a method to work out which button the action came from, set up a dictionary object with the slider value inside it, and then write it to a strong array accordingly.

MainViewController.h

```
int emotionNumber
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *array;
//Declare your slider and buttons
```

---

MainViewController.m

```
@implementation
@synthesise array;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[happyButton setTag:0];
[angryButton setTag:1];

array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:X]; <---- number of emotions
}

- (IBAction)setValue:(id)sender {

    // You will also want to keep track of emotionNumber (the int) here, and modify the
    //code below to write it to the correct place in the array.

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    switch (button.tag) {
        case 0:
            [dictionary setValue:slider.value forKey:@"angry"];
            [array addObject:dictionary];
            break;

        case 1:
            [dictionary setValue:slider.value forKey:@"happy"];
            [array addObject:dictionary];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```